# Is there a function to read the entire console?

Tags: c#, console, console-application

I am making a program in C#, and I would like to have a program do something like this:

```
while (true)
{
    var Key = Console.ReadKey();
    if (Key.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace)
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop - 1);
        Console.Write(new string(' ', Console.WindowWidth));
    }
    else
    {
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

and then do something like:

```
Console.ReadAllTextInConsole
```

to get all text currently in the console window and put it into a string. Is this possible?

Comment: Why `while (0 == 0)` ?

Comment: Is there a difference between (0 == 0) and (true)?

Comment: No there isn't, so why not just write `true` ?

Comment: This isn't even valid c# code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made this without last line delete, but it should do what you were looking for, give it a try:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var console = new ConsoleV2();

        while (true)
        {
            var input = Console.ReadLine();
            if (input != "print")
            {
                console.WriteLine(input);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(console.GetOutput());
            }
        }
    }
}

public class ConsoleV2
{
    private readonly StringBuilder _stringBuilder;

    public ConsoleV2()
    {
        _stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    }

    public void Write(string format, params object[] args)
    {
        _stringBuilder.Append(string.Format(format, args));
        Console.Write(format, args);
    }

    public void WriteLine(string format, params object[] args)
    {
        _stringBuilder.AppendLine(string.Format(format, args));
        Console.WriteLine(format, args);
    }

    public string GetOutput()
    {
        return _stringBuilder.ToString();
    }
}
```